# Symfony5: Call to a member function persist() on null

Tags: php, mysql, json, консоль, symfony

хочу написать команду, которая парсит из json и заносит в mysql сущность,
и вот после получения данных происходит такой метод:

```
   protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output): int
    {
        $books = $this->get_decoded_json($output);
        if (!$books) {
            return Command::FAILURE;
        }

        $em = $this->entityManager;

        $authors = array();
        foreach($books as $id=>$book) {
            $dbBook = new Book();

            $output->writeln("[$id][Title] $book->title");

            $dbBook->setTitle($book->title);
            $dbBook->setIsbn($book->isbn);
            $dbBook->setPageCount($book->pageCount);
            $dbBook->setStatus($book->status);

            // $dbBook->setPublishedDate($book->pageCount);
            // $dbBook->setThumbnailUrl($book->pageCount);
            // $dbBook->setShortDescription($book->pageCount);
            // $dbBook->setLongDescription($book->pageCount);

            // $this->log($output, $id, $book, 'publishedDate');
            $this->log($output, $id, $book, 'shortDescription');
            $this->log($output, $id, $book, 'longDescription');
            $this->log($output, $id, $book, 'thumbnailUrl');
            //$output->writeln($id.': '.$book->authors);
            //$output->writeln($id.': '.$book->categories);
            //$output->writeln("");
            $em->persist($dbBook);
        }
        $em->flush();
```

на что консоль отвечает ошибкой: Call to a member function persist() on null

Comment: приложите код всего класса вместе с внедрением Entity Manager'а. Именно там и закралась ошибка

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Dt8D-1Ge7T2c1X19ZMn2KNz2LqHoE5rvDAqfniicRNE/edit?usp=sharing  - вот в гугл документ положила весь класс, не знаю как еще его уместить

Comment: да, теперь там ошибка с подключением EntityManager:   Cannot autowire service "App\Command\JsonParserCommand": argument "$entityManager" of method "__construct()" references class "Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager  
  " but no such service exists. Try changing the type-hint to "Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface" instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$em` у вас со значением `null`, о чём и говорит ошибка. А узнать то, откуда "ноги растут" придётся воспользоваться отладкой. См. соответствующую тему:

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/701146/191482

а также во время отладки смотреть стэк вызова